# Error: Could not find or load main class in Spring boot kotlin new project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, kotlin, spring-tool-suite

I am learning spring boot with kotlin and this is my first application. I have created a starter project with STS but I am not able to run it. I am getting the following error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class 
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Following is my application settings:
[image]

Can someone please help me?

Console: [image]

Comment: Paste your stack trace.

Comment: where should I look for it? I only have the console with above error

Comment: Run the application and look the console

Comment: I run the app and get error in console. I have just added the screenshot of Console.

Comment: Then rebuild and try again

Comment: tried few times, it is always same.

Answer (score 2):

Check in your `build.gralde.kt` that the reference to the mainclass is correct:

```
mainClassName = 'TheMenschenApplicationKt'
```

You might even need a fully qualified namehere. And it's an upper K in TheMenschenApplicationKt.

This is required because of the way Kotlin compiles to Java Bytecode. The `fun main()` function in Kotlin is not attached to any class, but Java always requires a class and does not support classless functions.

The Kotlin compiler has to create a Java class. Because you already defined a class `Application` it created one with the suffix `Kt` for the functions in your Kotlin file `com/themenschen/app/TheMenschenApplication.kt`. You have to set this class so that the JVM can find it.

BTW a Jar file is just a Zip file, you can unpack it and see for yourself if the ApplicationKt.class is there.

Comment: I have added mainClassName but it is still not working. I doubt if kotlin is installed as I am not able to get any intellisense also. Do I need to install any plugin for kotlin? I am using latest STS on my mac.

Comment: Well, you do need to have the Kotlin Compiler installed, of course. Have you checked: https://docs.spring.io/sts/nan/v373/SpringToolSuiteAndKotlin.html